# Terser way to get the intensity of one pixel

Tags: image-processing, image

I want a function to return the intensity of one pixel notwithstanding the Color Space of the source image.

I wrote:

```
getIntensity[i_Image, pos_List] :=
 ColorConvert[Flatten@{PixelValue[i, pos]}, ImageColorSpace[i] -> "Grayscale"]
```

but it looks clumsy and there is probably a better way that I'm overlooking.

Test cases:

```
i = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
ig = ColorConvert[i, "Grayscale"];
getIntensity[i, {1, 1}]
getIntensity[ig, {1, 1}]

(*
  {0.172275}
  {0.172549}
*)
```

---

Note: Not very important right now, but it would be nice if the position could be specified as a rectangular region `{a ;; b, c ;; d}`

Comment: {a ;; b, c ;; d} will return the  the intensity of every pixel or a mean value?

Comment: @yode A list (matrix) with the intensities for every pixel

Comment: Incredible, how unterse it is to transform a `Span` specification to a `Take` specification! Working on this right now.

Comment: Here's a function. Should work in v9, though `ColorConvert` got updated in v10. `f[i_Image, c_List] := 
 ImageTake[i, 
    Sequence @@ (Replace[
        c, {h___, n_Integer, t___} :> {h, {n}, t}] /. Span -> List)] //
    ColorConvert[#, "Grayscale"] & // ImageData` I'm afraid, taking a span specification forces me to use a very clumsy replacement rule.

Comment: The golfed down version that takes a `Take` kind of part specification looks like this: `f[i_, c__] := ImageData@ColorConvert[ImageTake[i, c], "Grayscale"]`

Comment: @LLlAMnYP You should post a answer I think.It may be more suitable for our doctor's v9 than my solution.

Answer (score 5):

Reposting my comment as an answer.

This has the same caveat, as @yode mentioned: pixel coordinates (from top to bottom, *then* from left to right) vs "normal coordinates" (left to right, then upwards).

Perhaps this is terser, although it always returns a 2-d array, even if only of one element. The golfed down version doesn't take a `Span`:

```
f[i_, c__] := ImageData@ColorConvert[ImageTake[i, c], "Grayscale"]
```

> Usage:
>
> ```
> f[image, {row1, row2, step(optional)}, {col1, col2, step(optional)}]
> ```
>
> the part specification works exactly like `ImageTake`.

The ungolfed version accepts Belisarius' `{a ;; b, c ;; d}` desire (also with the step size, if need be):

```
f[i_Image, c_List] := ImageTake[i,
  Sequence @@ (Replace[ c, {h___, n_Integer, t___} :> {h, {n}, t}] /. Span -> List)] // 
    ColorConvert[#, "Grayscale"] & // ImageData
```

The replacement rule to accept `Span` is rather clumsy and can probably be improved. An integer specification will be equivalent to `n ;; n ;; 1`.

If we extend the code as

```
f[i_, c__] := ImageData@ColorConvert[ImageTake[
                ImageRotate[i, -Pi/2], c], "Grayscale"]
```

(or similarly in the ungolfed version), we'll get the "normal" coordinates. In this case the part specification will be first the x-range, then the y-range from bottom to top. It might be counterintuitive though, because the returned array will be essentially the image rotated clockwise.

Adding in the discussion in the comments: the image standard coordinates know nothing about the negative specifications, so I can probably assume that the `Span`-like argument will take only positive values. Because `ImageRotate` is horribly inefficient to simply get a coordinate transformation, and @Belisarius hinted at the use of `ImageTrim`, there's a very simple workaround available (no 3-argument `Span` specification though, sorry).

```
f[i_, c:{(_Span|_Integer)..}] := ImageData@ColorConvert[ImageTrim[i, Thread[List@@@c]-.5], "Grayscale"]
```

I have no idea, why Belisarius' two approaches (convert to grayscale, then get pixel value or vice versa) give different results. Mine is consistent with `getIntensity[ig, {1, 1}]`.

Comment: On the same line `ImageData@ColorConvert[ImageTrim[i, {c - .5, c - .5}], "Grayscale"]` uses image standard coordinates

Comment: Yes, that is vastly better. As @nikie alerted me over [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110373/imagedata-reverses-the-order-of-the-row-of-an-image/110406?noredirect=1#comment299431_110406), `ImageRotate` is a horribly inefficient way to do the coordinate transformation, although very straighforward.

Comment: @Dr.belisarius by the way, seeing as we're dealing with image standard coordinates, are negative specifications to refer to "`{x,y}` from last" at all relevant here? Because if not, there's a lot less corner cases to deal with, when implementing the expected behavior of `Span`.

Comment: I suspected the span thing could be cumbersome, so the  final note on the question. I like your answer, let the span rest in peace.

Comment: @Dr.belisarius actually if we don't use negative values for `Span`, it's super easy: with the coordinates specified as `a:{(_Span|_Integer)..}` feed them to `ImageTrim` as `Thread[List@@@a]-.5`

Comment: May I suggest you to pack the `ImageTrim` and that last comment in your answer?

Comment: @Dr.belisarius just did, though the answer is a bit cluttered now. No time to tidy up though, maybe some other time.

Answer (score 4):

```
fun[i_Image, rect_List] := 
 ImageMeasurements[i, "MeanIntensity", 
    Masking -> SparseArray[{# -> 1}, ImageDimensions[i]]] & /@ 
  Catenate@CoordinateBoundingBoxArray[rect]
```

Usage:

```
i = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
fun[i, {{2, 3}, {4, 5}}]
```

> {0.635294, 0.631373, 0.635294, 0.635294, 0.631373, 0.635294, 
>   0.635294, 0.631373, 0.635294}

---

Update:
I'm very sorry I make a mistake in the [Image Coordinate Systems](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImageProcessing.html#1708646374),And the code above serve a **Index Coordinates**.So we cann't use `SparseArray` as a mask unless you have a need in **Index Coordinates**.But this time let's face up to a **Pixel-aligned Image Coordinates**

When your object is a list of pixel:

```
fun1[i_Image, pos_List] := 
 ImageMeasurements[i, "MeanIntensity", 
    Masking -> 
     ReplacePixelValue[
      ConstantImage[0, ImageDimensions[i]], {# -> 1}]] & /@ pos
```

Usage:

```
fun1[i, {{1, 1}(*your test case*), {5, 6}, {10, 10}}]
fun1[ig, {{1, 1}(*your test case*), {5, 6}, {10, 10}}]
```

> {0.172549, 0.211765, 0.247059}
>
> {0.172549, 0.211765, 0.247059}

If your object is a region of pixel rectange:

```
fun2[i_Image, rect_List] := 
 ImageMeasurements[i, "MeanIntensity", 
    Masking -> 
     ReplacePixelValue[
      ConstantImage[0, ImageDimensions[i]], {# -> 1}]] & /@ 
  Catenate@CoordinateBoundingBoxArray[rect]
```

Usage:

```
fun2[i, {{1, 1}, {5, 8}}]
```

> {0.172549, 0.172549, 0.168627, 0.180392, 0.211765, 0.188235, 
>   0.184314, 0.188235, 0.172549, 0.172549, 0.168627, 0.180392, 0.211765, 
>   0.188235, 0.184314, 0.188235, 0.215686, 0.215686, 0.196078, 0.196078, 
>   0.188235, 0.223529, 0.215686, 0.207843, 0.2, 0.2, 0.184314, 0.196078, 
>   0.184314, 0.203922, 0.207843, 0.192157, 0.211765, 0.211765, 0.211765, 
>   0.203922, 0.207843, 0.211765, 0.196078, 0.207843}

Comment: I meant "terser". Like in more "brief, short, to the point, concise, succinct, crisp" :)

Comment: Only these option/function have more letters.but is brief actually I think.aha~

Comment: In any case, I upvoted without testing it (it is a bad practice!). But I'm in v9 and you're using v10 features, so no way to check. Could you include the results for my two test cases?